# Downloading Dropbox files one by one with wget

Tags: terminal, download, dropbox, wget

I have some huge images in a folder on the web version of Dropbox that I need to make a shell script to download them one by one (There isn't enough room on my SDD and can't download the whole folder). I know using "wget" I can download a file:

```
wget link_to_the_file
```

However since I have many images it is not feasible to get the download link of each of them manually. I'm looking for a way of obtaining downloading link for each of them through the shell. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox offers an [API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) you can use to write a program to list and download multiple files.

For instance, you can use [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)] to list files, and then use [/2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) to download them.

Those are links to the HTTPS endpoints, but there are corresponding native methods in [the official SDKs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation), if you want to use one of those.